# WPF FocusManager interferring with focus

Tags: wpf, tabs, tabbing, focusmanager

I have a grid, and in the grid I am setting my first element to be focused:

```
<Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=companyNameField}">
```

When the window opens, the correct control is focused.

But if I tab through the whole form, when the above focused field, should have the focus, there is no cursor evident anywhere on the window.

If I hit tab once more, it selects the control after the control that should be selected.

If I completely remove the focumanager attributes from my grid, I am correctly tabbing trough all my controls in the correct order.

Even stranger, if i leave in the focusmanager attributes and first click on the first text box and then focus through the entire form, then it selects my text box like any other control.

If you have any Ideas, I would love some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me, when I had some focus code in the code-behind fighting with the FocusManager.  Mine was hidden in the Load of a nested UserControl, so I didn't notice it.